The proper way to handling multiple user roles and 2 statues for changing logic and UI in React
i got a project has 3 users roles (parent - child - teacher) and each role has 2 different statues (booked - unbooked) that changes the UI and logic.
Example:-
the home header in the home page will be change based on the user role and the statues.
How to solve this problem without big chain of conditions ?
Wrong Answer ❌
  switch (userRole) {
    case 'parent':
      switch (status) {
        case 'booked':
          return // BookedParentComponent
        case 'unbooked':
          return // UnBookedParentComponent
      }

    case 'child':
      switch (status) {
        case 'booked':
          return // BookedChildComponent
        case 'unbooked':
          return // UnBookedChildComponent
      }

    case 'teacher':
      switch (status) {
        case 'booked':
          return // BookedTeacherComponent
        case 'unbooked':
          return // UnBookedTeacherComponent
      }
  }



With Dynamic components, no conditionals required.
The following sample code demoes it.
Note : For brevity, sample code handles only two components.
./src/App.js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <DynamicComponent userRole="parent" status="booked" />
      <br />
      <DynamicComponent userRole="parent" status="unbooked" />
    </>
  );
}

function DynamicComponent({ userRole, status }) {
  const Component = require(`./components/${status}${userRole}`).default;
  return <Component />;
}

./src/components/bookedparent.js
export default function BookedParentComponent() {
  return 'I am BookedParentComponent';
}

./src/components/unbookedparent.js
export default function UnBookedParentComponent() {
  return 'I am UnBookedParentComponent';
}

Test run output
On load of the app

Citation:
The Importance of React Dynamic Component Name: Insights

Thank you for your vote and confirmation.

You can define a nested object structure that maps the userRole and status to the correct component. This avoids the need for multiple switch or if statements and makes the code cleaner and more maintainable.

 const componentMap = {
  parent: {
    booked: 'BookedParentComponent',
    unbooked: 'UnBookedParentComponent',
  },
  child: {
    booked: 'BookedChildComponent',
    unbooked: 'UnBookedChildComponent',
  },
  teacher: {
    booked: 'BookedTeacherComponent',
    unbooked: 'UnBookedTeacherComponent',
  },
};

function getComponent(userRole, status) {
  // Return the appropriate component based on the role and status
  return componentMap[userRole]?.[status] || null; // Fallback to null if no match
}

// Usage example
const component = getComponent('parent', 'booked');
console.log(component); // Output: BookedParentComponent


You can use a map/object,
function returnComponent(userRole, status) {
  const components = {
    "parent-booked": BookedParentComponent,
    "parent-unbooked": UnBookedParentComponent,
    "child-booked": BookedChildComponent,
    "child-unbooked": UnBookedChildComponent,
    "teacher-booked": BookedTeacherComponent,
    "teacher-unbooked": UnBookedTeacherComponent,
  };

  return components[userRole + "-" + status];
}

Usage 1: Using ViewContainerRef and createComponent
// use it like this. Get the component and render it dynamically or use ngTemplateOutlet etc.

import {
  Component,
  ViewChild,
  ViewContainerRef,
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-dynamic-loader",
  template: `<ng-container #dynamicContainer></ng-container>`,
})
export class DynamicLoaderComponent {
  @ViewChild("dynamicContainer", { read: ViewContainerRef })
  container!: ViewContainerRef;

  loadComponent() {
    const componentRef = this.container.createComponent(
      this.returnComponent("parent", "booked")
    );
    componentRef.instance.someInput = "Dynamic Data";
  }

  returnComponent(userRole, status) {
    const components = {
      "parent-booked": BookedParentComponent,
      "parent-unbooked": UnBookedParentComponent,
      "child-booked": BookedChildComponent,
      "child-unbooked": UnBookedChildComponent,
      "teacher-booked": BookedTeacherComponent,
      "teacher-unbooked": UnBookedTeacherComponent,
    };

    return components[userRole + "-" + status];
  }
}


Usage 2: Get the template of that component and render it like this,
<ng-template #template let-data="data">
  <div>{{ data }}</div>
</ng-template>

<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template; context: { $implicit: 'Dynamic Content' }"></ng-container>

